# How to SVN merge trunk into a branch (SVN 1.6) using Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, merge

I created a branch and then made changes to trunk which need merging into the branch. TortoiseSVN has a nice handy merge branch->trunk utility, but to do it this way round do I have to manually merge specific revision ranges?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Bringing a branch up to date with trunk is usually very simple with SVN 1.6.  This version keeps track of the specific trunk revisions already in the branch and knows how to only merge in the revisions you don't have in the branch.  TortoiseSVN takes full advantage of SVN's merge tracking feature.

When merging new trunk changes into a branch, choose the "Merge a range of revisions" option.  Leaving the revision range entry blank will cause Tortoise to merge all new changes from trunk without you having to figure out what revisions those are.

Here is the TortoiseSVN documentation on [merge tracking](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html#tsvn-dug-merge-tracking).

Comment: This answer, and the documentation (not that I could see) don't show the steps in TortoiseSVN: Right click on your Branch, go to TortoiseSVN, choose "Merge a range of revisions", click next, your main/trunk should be listed in the "URL to merge from" box and your branch should be in the "Working copy" area. Click Next, do a test merge, then merge depending on conflicts, resolve any conflicts, then do a commit on your branch. I use TortoiseSVN 1.8

Answer (score 2):

If you made the branch using 1.6, the branch will have the information to allow merging from trunk to branch automagically.